React Native CLI: Error 'Unable to resolve module' after installing any new library
I am facing an issue in my React Native project where, after installing any new library, I get the following error:
[Error: undefined Unable to resolve module @notifee/react-native from C:\Users\Fatih\Desktop\typescript mobile dev\heyyo\App.tsx: @notifee/react-native could not be found within the project or in these directories:
This problem occurs not only with @notifee/react-native, but with every new library I install. The error persists until I manually delete the node_modules folder and reinstall all dependencies using yarn install.
Every time I install a new library I have to uninstall node modules and install it which is bothering
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or found a permanent fix for this?

Remove spaces from the path name "typescript mobile dev".
node will be parsing it as
C:\Users\Fatih\Desktop\typescript%20mobile%20dev\heyyo\App.tsx

which does not exist.
